# vertical-align top is not working with dt and dd elements

Tags: css

I'm trying to make `vertical-align:top` works in this example:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #E6E9F0;
  border: solid 1px black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
dt,dd {
    display: inline-block;
}
dd {
    white-space: break-spaces;
    margin: 0;
}
dt {
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div class="container">
    <dt>Text</dt>
    <dd>Very very veeeeeeeeeeeeeery veeeeeery very very very long text</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

As you can see it doesn't work, another issue is that the content gets outside the container.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: [not the answer] Oh, inline-block for this issue... inline-block has [whitespace issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements) between elements so you'll need to think on that also. My 5 cents - use flex or grid, you'll be a lot happier :)

Comment: vertical-align: top; need to be added to dt,dd not the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #E6E9F0;
  border: solid 1px black;
  vertical-align: top;
display: table;
}
dt,dd {
    display: table-cell;
}
dd {
    white-space: break-spaces;
    word-break: break-all;
    margin: 0;
}
dt {
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <dt>Text</dt>
  <dd>Very very veeeeeeeeeeeeeery veeeeeery very very very long text</dd>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dd {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
}
```

try using css ellipsis and add vertical align - top to dt

```
dt {
vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use just `display: flex`.

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/oNzYLdN